# Manipulating config file dynamically

Tags: .net

Is it possible to change the contents of web.config at run time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you modify the web.config appSettings at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719928/how-do-you-modify-the-web-config-appsettings-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do so by using WebConfigurationManager class.

```
Configuration cfg = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
ConnectionStringSettings consettings = cfg.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["conkey"];
consettings.ConnectionString = "updated value";           
cfg.Save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

The safe way is to write to `appSettings`: [Writing to Your .NET Application's Config File](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/07/13/879.aspx)
But you can [also hack it](http://geekswithblogs.net/AzamSharp/archive/2005/10/09/56457.aspx) (don't do this).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code to update the web.config file at runtime.

Lets say web.config has a key like this

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="conkey" connectionString="old value" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And here is the C# code to update the web.config file.

```
 string path = Server.MapPath("Web.config");
             string newConnectionString = "updated value"; // Updated Value

            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument(); 
            xDoc.Load(path);

            XmlNodeList nodeList = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("connectionStrings");

            XmlNodeList nodeconnectionStrings = nodeList[0].ChildNodes;

            XmlAttributeCollection xmlAttCollection = nodeconnectionStrings[0].Attributes;

            xmlAttCollection[1].InnerXml = newConnectionString; // for value attribute

            xDoc.Save(path); // saves the web.config file
```

This code worked for me. However it is recommended  not to do this.