# Updating a xml file from form fields in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Hi I have the following class which provides access to a xml file:

```
public class AppConfig
{
    public string AppConfigPath = "~/admin.config.xml";
    XmlDocument SiteConfig = new XmlDocument();

    public string getAppConfigParam(string param) 
    {

        SiteConfig.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(AppConfigPath));
        string reqParam = SiteConfig.SelectSingleNode("//cmsAppConfig")[param].InnerText;
        return reqParam;
    }

    public void setAppConfigParam(string paramTitle, string paramValue) 
    {
        SiteConfig.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(AppConfigPath));

        XmlNodeList ConfigNodes = SiteConfig.SelectSingleNode("//cmsAppConfig").ChildNodes;

        foreach (XmlNode node in ConfigNodes) 
        {
            if (node.Name == paramTitle) 
            {
                node.InnerText = paramValue;
            }
        }

        SiteConfig.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(AppConfigPath));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
    }

}
```

I am using the class in the following event to update some app settings but only the first node which is the globalskin gets updated.

```
protected void btnSaveAppConfig_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (IsValid) {
        AppConfig myAppConfig = new AppConfig();
        myAppConfig.setAppConfigParam("globalskin", drpAppTheme.SelectedValue.ToString());
        myAppConfig.setAppConfigParam("homefeedsurl", txtNewsFeedUrl.Text.Trim());
        myAppConfig.setAppConfigParam("homefeedstitle", txtNewsFeedTitle.Text.Trim());
    }
}
```

What changes to do I need to make to make the change to all fields?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: The docs state "The Initialize method must be called before this method can be used."...have you done that? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee784825(v=CS.20).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this line in your `setAppConfigParam` method:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
```

Is causing an immediate redirect, so that the other two calls to `setAppConfigParam` never even get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this xml file your web config (or 'critical file')?  If so, then when you save the config file, it's restarting your appdomain.  Is there a reason you're treating the config file as a plain old xml doc?  If it is, in fact, a .net configuration file, [try this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719928/how-do-you-modify-the-web-config-appsettings-at-runtime)...

Comment: This file is not the .net app config file. it's  just a normal xml file which holds information about user skin, news feeds path etc