# Program cannot find app.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

> // Set LastRun to now
>               config.AppSettings.Settings["LastRun"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
>               // Save all settings
>               config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

This code was working fine in my development server but not in my production server. It seems like my program is unable to communicate with my app.config file. I have checked all the "obvious" . . Any ideas ... ?

Comment: Did you verify `app.config` exists on the server? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Come on. . . all of the "obvious" . . . it's there for sure ... It just gives me a "System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String" when I try to assign a value from the config file to a variable as well as this code above ^^^ which saves the appsettings

Comment: Does the application have permissions on the folder/files?

Comment: Yes it has full permisions

Comment: what kind of app is it? Web? Console? Winforms?

Comment: web , it updates a list in Sharepoint

Comment: the web app is going to try load AppSettings from web.config

Comment: I mean. It's been working fine in one server and when i copied it over to another server it doesn't work. . . . Does this stir up any ideas ?

Comment: how is the config variable being initialized?

Answer (score 2):

From your code example, I cannot tell how your config variable is initialized. But, from the comments, you have a web app.  Unless you are attempting to load a specific app.config file, the web app will attempt to get AppSettings from web.config.

It's not a good idea to programatically change the values of web.config. Changing web.config will cause an application restart.

If you have a different app.config for storing this type of information, that would be better than trying to change web.config. But you'll have to specifically load the file, something like this:

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("yourPath\app.config");
```

`ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration()` is intended for use within an executable application not a web app. Try using `WebConfigurationManager` as shown above.

You find some more information in this [SO question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719928/how-do-you-modify-the-web-config-appsettings-at-runtime?lq=1).

More information can be found in this [SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500683/unable-to-write-appsettings-of-web-config-on-production-server?lq=1).

Comment: Ive been using :
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None); . . . won't this work as well?

Comment: It is intended for executables. Try WebConfigurationManager. Look at those other questions I linked.

Comment: I'm getting an error: 
System.Configuration.configurationElement.this[System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty]' is inaccessible due to its protection level: 
Configuration cfg = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("yourPath\app.config"); String test1 = cfg.AppSettings["LastRun"]; //error

Comment: Look at the answer in the first SO question I linked.  You'll likely have to adjust the permissions of the folder where the config file exists.

Comment: All the permissions are fine. Double checked. WebConfigurationManager isn't working. I don't know why I get an "inaccessible" error.  Don't really know what else to do . . .