# Add key to App.config programmatically C#

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I'm trying to programmatically add and save a key to my App.config file. My code is below, I've seen tons of different examples like this, and mine is not working. I'm trying to add a brand new key, not modify an existing. This is a console application, and I did make sure to add a Reference to System.configuration.

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;

namespace AddValuesToConfig
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("key1", "value");

            // Save the changes in App.config file.

            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

        }
    }
}
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>

    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It's because you're checking the wrong file probably. When you use `OpenExeConfiguration` it's going to update <yourapp>.exe.config, not app.config.

Comment: I checked <myapp>.exe.config, that looks exactly like the App.config and has not changed. How do I specify to update the App.config?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Update (Add/Modify/Delete) keys in AppSettings section of web.config at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653621/how-to-update-add-modify-delete-keys-in-appsettings-section-of-web-config-at-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you run this code under debugger in Visual Studio. Thing is when you do this, Visual Studio really runs not YourApp.exe, but YourApp.vshost.exe file. That means you are adding your key to YourApp.vshost.exe.config file instead of YourApp.exe.config. Try run without debugger, it should work then.

EDIT to answer comment below. Topic starter claims that VS does not write even to .vshost.exe.config when debugging, and I thought that is true. However little investigation shows that it DOES write to .vshost.config.exe file, BUT when you stop debugging, it will overwrite contents of your .vshost.exe.config with your .exe.config. So after your debugging session ends, you might think it did not write anything at all. However, if you put breakpoint right after config.Save() statement and open .vshost.exe.config file - you will see changes there.

Comment: There was the issue! Now does the debugger actually write the key somewhere? I checked vshost.exe.Config, and did not see any change there.

Comment: I just checked mine and I see added key there. Maybe you mess Debug\Release folders?

Comment: No I was wrong in comment above, mine .vshost.exe.config contains added key just because it was copied from main .exe.config file. VS does not write there under debugger.

Comment: @kyle_13 updated my post with what really happens in this case.

Comment: Wow, such strange behavior, but I get the same result as you.

Answer (score 1):

for write:

```
 public static bool SetAppSettings<TType>(string key, TType value)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                return false;

            Configuration appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(GetCurrentApplicationPath());
            AppSettingsSection appSettings = (AppSettingsSection)appConfig.GetSection("appSettings");
            if (appSettings.Settings[key] == null)
                appSettings.Settings.Add(key, value.ToString());
            else
                appSettings.Settings[key].Value = value.ToString();
            appConfig.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

for read:

```
public static TType GetAppSettings<TType>(string key, TType defaultValue = default(TType))
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                return defaultValue;
            AppSettingsReader appSettings = new AppSettingsReader();
            return (TType)appSettings.GetValue(key, typeof(TType));
        }
        catch
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44419822/109941) worked for me:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set(item.Key, item.Value);
```