# How to set app settings without save in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, app-config

We want to develop an application that gets the configuration items from a json file and stores the key&values at ConfigurationManager.AppSettings. But AppSettings dictionary is readonly. 
We **don't** want to update or save the app.config file. This operation have to be at memory. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653621/how-to-update-add-modify-delete-keys-in-appsettings-section-of-web-config-at-r

Comment: @Amit if you think it's a duplicate, why not flag it as such?

Comment: @Fildor I don't know how to flag as duplicate. Ok....got it.

Comment: Agreed I think this may be a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

The answer was so easy. I found in the deep of other topics.

[**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44419822/4141953)

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set(configItem.Key, configItem.Value.ToString());`