# Update IIS webconfig

Tags: iis, web-config

I have created a C# project. Now I want to save an IP address in the web.config file with the help of key and value.

```
<add key="ip" value="xxxx.xxx.x.xxx" />
```

Now I am able to read the value with the help of key name and also able to update the value of the key. It's running in localhost successfully.

But if I put the files in IIS I can read the value but can't update the key value. Error like this is showing in Mozilla Firebug. The error is as follows

> NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error
>
> Access to the path \u0027C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Order1\v1y5ay43.tmp\u0027 is denied.

I stuck over here. I Google it but did not find any solution.

Comment: Are you trying to have your web app modify the config file?

Comment: yes Tim you are absolutely right. Actually client ip address will be save in web.config. And he can modify the ip address form the app. A form which has a textbox and a button should be provided to the client.

Comment: Take a look at this answer for an example:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/719941/745969

Comment: Yes Tim i have seen this before. Its working successfully in localhost. But when i publish it in IIS the issue arises. Am i missing  something to provide to IIS to fully access the web.config?

Comment: Make sure the account the app pool is using has rights to read/write to the directory the Web.config is in.

Comment: Please elaborate Tim. May be this is the answer of my issue.

Comment: You're web application runs under a user account (the default varies depending on the version of IIS, or you can set it to a specific account.  In IIS, see which App Pool "owns" your app, then see what account is running the App Pool (like `Network Service`, for instance).  Then check and see if that account has write permissions to the root of the application (it already has read).

Comment: Thank you very much Tim.Let me check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't do that.

A web app cannot modify it's own config file. It is a security measure that you absolutely should NOT circumvent.

Other options:
Store the value in the session state. Or in the cache? Or in a global static hashtable?

Normally client specific stuff should be stored in the session state (if you have that enabled).

Remember that you likely have multiple clients at the same time, so you would need to keep track of that.

Note: Why would you want to store the IP? It is a property readily available to all your codebehind classes - so why store it?