# Update appSettings from code behind

Tags: vb.net, web-config

I' trying to update key value from code behind and it seemed like web.config updated but value didn't saved.
appSetting there is nothing special:

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="Default" value="1.11"/>
    <add key="Company" value="1.078"/>
    <add key="Customer" value="1.1"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Here is the code that must update appSettings key value:

```
 Protected Sub btnSaveDefault_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveDefault.Click
        Dim config As Configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/")
        config.AppSettings.Settings.Item("Default").Value = tbDefault.Text
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I found solution myself. The problem was in the other piece of code.
So each time on Page Load code giving me old value and If Page.IsPostBack fixed this issue.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            tbCompany.Text = Convert.ToSingle(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Company"))
            tbDefault.Text = Convert.ToSingle(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Default"))
            tbUser.Text = Convert.ToSingle(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Customer"))
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this help ...

```
System.Configuration.Configuration objConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");   

    objConfig.AppSettings.Settings["DEFAULT_PASSWORD"].Value = password;
    objConfig.Save();
```

follow this link .. [Getting error while changing Appsettings value in Web config from code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269868/getting-error-while-changing-appsettings-value-in-web-config-from-code-behind)