# How to update config file from code behind page in C#

Tags: c#

I am working on a web application which extracts data from databases. Databases are residing on server. I want the user to provide Server Name, username and password from the web application, which will help me to modify my connection string in web.config file from the code behind page. So, how can I update the config file from the code behind page in C#?

Guide me on what do I need to do here.

Comment: Why not build up a `IDbConnection` instead of edit the web.config?  Editing the web.config will make the changes active for all current users.

Comment: Share the code you have done so far

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719928/how-do-you-modify-the-web-config-appsettings-at-runtime

Comment: @Davin:IDbConnection??

Comment: @Perk yes [IDbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection.aspx).  Maybe [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) will help as well.

Comment: If server, user name and password are user-specific settings, then they belong on the client side, not in your web application's config file (which is very likely located on the server side).

Comment: @stakx because, my application will take connection string and other parameters from config file, i want to update the same as per user requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the code below:

```
// using System.Configuration;
// using System.IO;
var fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = File.Exists("XYZ.exe.config") ? "XYZ.exe.config" : "XYZ.config";
string path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, key);
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
var config = System.Configuration.Configuration; 
config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Item(key).Value = path;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Comment: That answer would've been better if (1) you would only have posted the relevant bit of code, (2) explained it, and (3) posted C# code instead of VB.NET code (since the question is tagged C#) -- I've taken care the last issue.