# Write and access frequent changing information

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a requirement where I need to write few information which will be changed frequently after the application gets deployed on server. Is there any way I can keep those information on some files of my asp.net application which when required can be updated and accessed in the application.

I tried to add the information in Web.config as that can be updated after deployment.Here is the code

```
<QueryConstants>
<add name ="SColumnName" value="UserId,First Name,Last Name,Description" />
<add name ="IColumnName" value="Company Name,Account Active Status" />
</QueryConstants>
```

but I am not able to access by the values from the keys.
How to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use app settings section as below in your web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add name ="SColumnName" value="UserId,First Name,Last Name,Description" />
    <add name ="IColumnName" value="Company Name,Account Active Status" />
</appSettings>
```

then you can read as below

```
var sColumnName= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SColumnName"];
var iColumnName= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IColumnName"];
```

also check [How do you modify the web.config appSettings at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719928/how-do-you-modify-the-web-config-appsettings-at-runtime)