# How to modify a key in web.config file through the code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, iis, web-config

If I have in the `web.config` file of web application :

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="DD" value="567_Access"/>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
</appSettings>
```

---

I know how to read the data in appSettings sections like this :

```
 string accessD = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DD"];
```

---

But I want to know how to **Modify (Set)** the value of a key in `appSettings`
Through the code ?

(I want through a specific check to this value to stop the application under some circumstances)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719928/how-do-you-modify-the-web-config-appsettings-at-runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap configFile = new System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configFile.ExeConfigFilename = "ConsoleTester.exe.config";  //name of your config file, can be from your app or external
System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFile, System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = config.AppSettings.Settings;
settings["DD"].Value = "007_Access";
config.Save();
```