# Read appSettings section from Web.config file using WebConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, appsettings, configurationmanager, webconfigurationmanager

I'm developing a WinForm application with C# and .NET Framework 4.7.

I want to open a Web.config file, read its appSetting section and modify it.

To open it, I use this:

```
 System.Configuration.Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
```

It opens it but, when I try to get the keys with:

```
string[] keys = config.AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys;
```

I get a null array.

This is the appSetting section:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>

  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

    <add key="MinRemainingCodes" value="100" />
    <!-- Others keys -->
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

Maybe the problem is that it is not opening the file, but in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.openwebconfiguration?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_Configuration_WebConfigurationManager_OpenWebConfiguration_System_String_) say:

> The virtual path to the configuration file. If null, the root
>   Web.config file is opened.

Maybe I don't understand what means with `root` because the program and the `Web.config` file are in the same folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the following example work for you? [WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.appsettings?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples)

Comment: try `string[] keys =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys?`

Comment: @DanielShillcock Thanks, but it doesn't work. I have updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.openwebconfiguration?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_Configuration_WebConfigurationManager_OpenWebConfiguration_System_String_) includes the following description of the `path` parameter:

> The virtual path to the configuration file. If null, the root Web.config file is opened.

Because your application is not running under IIS as a Web Site, the `Web.config` that is being opened is actually that which lives in the .NET Framework installation folder itself (in my case, that's `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config`).

[`WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.openmappedwebconfiguration?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_Configuration_WebConfigurationManager_OpenMappedWebConfiguration_System_Web_Configuration_WebConfigurationFileMap_System_String_) allows you to map virtual directories to physical directories in order to allow you to specify a virtual path that is mapped to your own local directory. Here's the code I've used to make this work:

```
var webConfigurationFileMap = new WebConfigurationFileMap();

webConfigurationFileMap.VirtualDirectories.Add(
    string.Empty,
    new VirtualDirectoryMapping(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), isAppRoot: true));

var webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(
    webConfigurationFileMap,
    string.Empty);
```

As you can see, I'm mapping the root virtual directory (using `string.Empty`) to the application's directory (using `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`).

Answer (score 0):

OpenWebConfiguration is supposed to receive the path to your web config if I'm not mistaken and you are passing it `null`.

Try like this:

```
config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
```

Also this might help you: [How do you modify the web.config appSettings at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719928/how-do-you-modify-the-web-config-appsettings-at-runtime)

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following exception: "The virtual relative path '~' of the application is not allowed here."

Comment: Have you tried reading a specific value maybe? To make sure you are able to actually open the web config with null. Something like: config.AppSettings.Settings.Item("myKey").Value = txtmyKey.Text. If that works then try "Request.ApplicationPath" instead of '~' or null

Comment: I'm developing a WinForm application. I'm opening it from that app, not from the ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you use web.config for a desktop application. It doesn't sound correct. Try to use app.config instead.
Second, WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration opens the Web-application configuration file

As for the topic, to get information from the config file try to use

```
var keys = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys
```